# Sorting qtablewidget by qcombobox currentText

Tags: python, sorting, pyside, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have a qtablewidget and one of its cell widgets in each row is a qcombobox. I would like to sort the table according to the contents of the qcomboboxes in each row. How to do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
self.table = QTableWidget(0,5)
self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.table.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.table_sorting_clicked)

'''some code here'''

def table_sorting_clicked(self,logicalIndex,order):

'''some code here'''
```

Answer (score 0):

- install a `QSignalMapper`
- connect it to the sorting method
- connect `currentTextChanged()`-signal of the comboboxes with the signalmapper
- and set the itemData of the cells with the comboboxes to `currentText()` (necessary, because there is nothing to sort, if all cells contain only comboboxes)
- update itemData if `currentText()` changes.

here a working example in pyqt5:

```
class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRowCount(5)
        self.setColumnCount(2)

        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.table_sorting_clicked)
        self.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.changeSortOrder)

        texts = []
        for i in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']:
            texts.append(i)

        for i in range(0,self.rowCount()):
            combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo.addItems(texts)
            combo.setCurrentIndex(i)
            combo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(combo, i)
            self.setItem(i,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i+1)))
            self.setItem(i,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem())
            self.setCellWidget(i,1,combo)
            self.item(i,1).setData(0, combo.currentText())

        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortOrder = 0

    def table_sorting_clicked(self, index):
        self.item(index,1).setData(0, self.cellWidget(index,1).currentText())
        self.sortByColumn(1,self.sortOrder)
        # edit 04.09.2015 19:40 
        #this doesn't work correctly if called several times
        # add the following code:
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.signalMapper.removeMappings(self.cellWidget(i,1))
            self.cellWidget(i,1).currentTextChanged.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(self.cellWidget(i,1), i)

    def changeSortOrder(self,logicalIndex,order):
        self.sortOrder = order
        self.sortByColumn(logicalIndex,self.sortOrder)
```

But perhaps using a delegate would be the better choice for Your purposes. There You can set a QListWidget as editor/selector for the user and You don't need to set item data additionally, the signals will be simpler:

```
class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, t, parent=None,):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self) 
        self.setParent(parent) 
        self.editorTexte = t

    def createEditor(self,parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            return QtWidgets.QListWidget(parent)
        return QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self,parent, option, index)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = str(index.data())
        if index.column() == 1:
            for i, v in enumerate(self.editorTexte):
                item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(v)
                editor.addItem(item)
                if v == value:
                    editor.setCurrentItem(editor.item(i)) 
            x = self.parent().columnViewportPosition(index.column())
            y = self.parent().rowViewportPosition(index.row())
            w = self.parent().columnWidth(index.column())
            h = self.parent().rowHeight(index.row())*5
            editor.setGeometry(x,y,w,h)
        else:
            QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.setEditorData(self, editor, index)

    def setModelData(self,editor,model,index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            v = editor.currentItem().text()
        else:
            v = editor.text()
        model.setData(index, v)

class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRowCount(5)
        self.setColumnCount(2)

        texts = []
        for i in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']:
            texts.append(i)
        self.setItemDelegate(MyDelegate(texts, self))

        for i in range(0,self.rowCount()):
            self.setItem(i,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i+1)))
            self.setItem(i,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(texts[i]))

        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortOrder = 0
        self.sortByColumn(1,self.sortOrder)
        self.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.changeSortOrder)

    def changeSortOrder(self,logicalIndex,order):
        self.sortOrder = order
        self.sortByColumn(logicalIndex,self.sortOrder)
```

Comment: thx @a_manthey_67 i tried your edited solution. it is giving me some trouble simply because the cell that has the combobox now needs to have another btn in it, so i am creating a widget that sets the horizontal layout which contains the 2 widgets (the combobox is widget number 1 in the layout). I am trying to make this fit in the code but am not getting any luck :(
using self.cellWidget(i,1).layout().itemAt(0).widget().currentText()

Comment: it always gives a fatal error without citing the reason for that

Comment: what is the button for? the tablewidget is sorted, if the selection in one cell is changed.

Comment: the button is for setting the color to show the old status of the first cell in the row. unrelated to the combo box but has to be in the same layout and cell as the combo box

Comment: and it shouldn't sort when the index of the combobox is changed,  only based on the content of the combo that is already there if that makes sense.

Comment: textChanged signal is used, so tableWidget is only sorted, when the text in combo is changed. But i think, self.cellWidget(i,1) is in the layout, so it should be self.item(i,1).layout()....if not, you should post a new question with your code.